# Java - How integrate extracted words from pdf files to MYSQL for indexing?

Tags: java, mysql, pdf

I have a simple application in Java, written to locate a PDF file and extract all the text inside it and stores it in a **HashSet**.

I also have a database created in MySQL with a table consisting `columns ID, Location PATH, and Word`.
The location path is supposed to store the path of PDF that it reads and extracts the words from. For example, `"D:/PDF/my.pdf`".

The Word is supposed to store all the words extracted from that particular PDF file in the hashSet.

The problem is how to I integrate by storing the hashSet to my database table so that it keeps the location of path and the words accordingly when I run it?

This is the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HashSet<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("D:/PDF/my.pdf"))) {

            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");

                    for (String word : words) {
                        uniqueWords.add(word);

                    }

                }
               System.out.println(uniqueWords);

            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
        }

        MysqlAccess connection=new MysqlAccess();
        connection.readDataBase();

    }

}
```

SQL connection code:

```
public class MysqlAccess {
    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public void readDataBase() throws Exception {
        try {
            // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Setup the connection with the DB
            connect = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://126.32.3.20/fulltext_ltat?"
                            + "user=root&password=root");

            // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
            statement = connect.createStatement();
            System.out.print("Connected");
            // Result set get the result of the SQL query

            preparedStatement = connect
                    .prepareStatement("insert into  fulltext_ltat.index_detail values (default, ?, ?)");

            preparedStatement.setString(1, "D:\\Full Text Indexing\\testIndex");
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "test");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            resultSet = statement
                    .executeQuery("select * from fulltext_ltat.index_detail");



            writeResultSet(resultSet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            close();
        }

    }



    private void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        // ResultSet is initially before the first data set
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            // It is possible to get the columns via name
            // also possible to get the columns via the column number
            // which starts at 1
            // e.g. resultSet.getSTring(2);
            String path = resultSet.getString("path");
            String word = resultSet.getString("word");



            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("path: " + path);
            System.out.println("word: " + word);

        }
    }


    private void close() {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (connect != null) {
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

EDIT: For anyone unclear of what I mean ,

Let's say I have a PDF file called `"my.pdf"` . When I extract the words that that file and stores the unique word in a hashset, I would like it to also be stored in the table I created in the mySQL.
 Say, that pdf is located in `"D:/Folder/my.pdf"` then the table should be like:

```
ID Location                Word 
1 "D:/FOLDER/my.pdf"       family 
2 "D:/FOLDER/my.pdf"       chicken....... and it goes on and on
```

Would this even be doable?

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean: "keeps the location of path and the words accordingly"?  Q: Is there any particular reason for using a HashSet?  Just to ensure uniqueness of each word?

Comment: I'm not sure if `default` is a valid literal value which can be used in the `VALUES` clause of a MySQL insert.

Comment: @paulsm4 I edited the post for better explanation

Comment: ASSUMPTIONS: 1) you want to save each "word" in each file.  2) You want to save both the word and the file in your DB.  3) If the same word occurs in two files, you'll save both rows in the DB.  4) If the same word occurs twice in the same file, then one row in the DB.  SUGGESTION: concatenate "word" + "path" when you add to the HashSet; split into "word" and "path" when you write to the database

Comment: @paulsm4 Yup the assumptions are correct

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions that might work for you:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PopulateDatabase {

    // Read all the words in the file
    private static Set<String> getWordsFromFile(File pdfFile) throws IOException  {
        Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>();
        // PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
        // ...
        //   for (String word : words) {
        //      uniqueWords.add(word);
        //      ...
        return uniqueWords;
    }

    private static void updateDB(File pdfFile, Set<String>uniqueWords) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        // Open DB
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://126.32.3.20/fulltext_ltat?user=root&password=root");

        // Insert rows
        for (String word : uniqueWords) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
                conn.prepareStatement("insert into  fulltext_ltat.index_detail values (default, ?, ?)");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }

        // Close DB
        conn.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read filepath for .pdf from cmd-line
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("USAGE: PopulateDatabase <myPdfFiles>");
            return;
        }

        // Convert to Java "File" object.
        File pdfFile = new File(args[0]);
        if (!pdfFile.exists() ) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + args[0] + " does not exist!");
            return;
        }

        try {   
            // Parse file
            Set<String> words = getWordsFromFile(pdfFile);

            // Update database
            updateDB(pdfFile, words);

            // Done
            System.out.println("Done: #/words: " + words.size() + ", pdfFile: " + pdfFile.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

You could modify the code slightly to allow for multiple files or wildcards.  You could also add another method to query the rows added.

To save space in your database, you might give each filepath an ID (rather than store the entire filepath string for each and every word).

'Hope that helps...